# Keep rainmeter from minimizing

Tags: windows-7, desktop, rainmeter

HI!

Just been playing around with Rainmeter and I notice that if I want to go look at my desktop and I click on the bottom right square in win7 that minimizes to the desktop, the rainmeter "gadget" gets minimized as well, not letting me read what I want to see. Is there something I can configure to make it stay up? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By default *Rainmeter* positions are set to normal (like any other window).

`Right-click` on your gadget, then click --> `Setting` --> `Position`-->
Now you should see half a dozen options ranging from `Always on Top` to `On Desktop`.

Click `On Desktop` then when you press `Show Desktop` it wont minimise the *Rainmeter* gadgets.

If you have a lot of gadgets that need placing on the desktop then right click any of your gadgets -->`Rainmeter Menu` --> `Edit Settings`... (which should bring up a text file).

In the file `Find&Replace` the string `AlwaysOnTop=0` with `AlwaysOnTop=-2` and click on `Replace All`.

Done.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have a powershell script that does this, though I can't remember where I got it from. Feel guilty posting it without an author, but it's very, very useful: [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2502059/Misc/aerofix.ps1)

I don't use rainmeter, so you'll have to stick in the executable name yourself, but that script defines a function that takes an executable file argument, and only affects running processes - PS is a bit slow to start up, though, so the timing works out if everything is autostarting.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the gadget and choosing "always on top", whilst it means it goes on all windows, it does mean that it will stay there when you click the button to go to desktop or hover on it.

Apart from this, gadgets should always be visible when the desktop is shown even if the "always on top" option is not selected, so if it is not visible - it is probably an error in the gadget.